# Excel Cell View Defaults to the Top

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a cell as a console window to display the status of the process. This console window is similar to a windows/linux cmd console in which it is suppose to scroll down as more information is displayed. However, as  new lines of string gets added to the bottom, the cell doesnt scroll down. Instead, The view remains on the top.

I am not looking to add new strings to the top of the cell. just the bottom
i tired cell alignment. it didnt do anything other then change the alignment.
I have to do it this way bc the application.statusbar is not an option.
Any help would be appreciated.
I cant use any activeX form controls bc there is a bug that warps the the font.

Comment: Do you need all the content to be available in the cell, or could you instead just display the last (eg) 10 lines?

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with just seeing the last few lines:

```vb
Sub testIt()
    Dim n
    For n = 1 To 40
        'add line, clearing existing every 10 lines
        AddConsoleLine "This is line #" & n & " at " & Now, (n Mod 10 = 0)
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    Next n
End Sub

'add a new line to A1 (optionally after clearing existing content)
Sub AddConsoleLine(txt, Optional Reset As Boolean = False)
    Const MAX_LINES As Long = 5                     'max # of lines to show
    Static lines As New Collection                  'preverved between calls
    Dim n As Long, arr()
    If Reset Then Set lines = New Collection        '[optional] clear existing lines
    If lines.Count = MAX_LINES Then lines.Remove 1  'remove first line
    lines.Add txt                                   'add new line at end
    ReDim arr(1 To lines.Count)                     'transfer lines to array
    For n = 1 To lines.Count
        arr(n) = lines(n)
    Next n
    [A1].Value = Join(arr, vbLf)                    'join array (faster)
End Sub
```

Comment: Not what i am looking for, but this is a still really good. I will end up using it. ty